# Is it bad for SEO to return a 404 for a page that is temporarily unavailable instead of a redirect to the home page?

Tags: seo, redirects, web-crawlers, googlebot, 404

Imagine a site that contains 100's of 'homepages' for merchants. (e.g. `www.example.com/cool_merchant`)

Some of these pages may exist for long periods, build up a nice SEO presence, and then be temporarily disabled for some time (e.g. a few weeks).

How bad for SEO is it for bots to see these pages return 404 for a while? Should I show bots a 302 instead?

*Note that the user will be directed to the home page with an AngularJS app (not a 'real' 302). By default the bot will see a 404 so I am wondering if we need to cater for bots specifically.*

Comment: "temporarily disabled for some time." - How long is "some time"; a few days, a few months?

Comment: good question. let's say, a few weeks

Comment: What is the reason for disabling the pages temporarily?

Answer (score 5):

A 302 to the home page is likely to be seen as a soft-404 anyway, so that's unlikely to be of any benefit.

A 404 can be perceived as temporary (a 410 is more permanent) and if the page doesn't exist then a 404 is certainly valid. There's not a lot you can do; if the page doesn't exist then it doesn't exist.

However, if this is really a "temporary" thing and its absence is planned. Then a 503 "Service Unavailable" status might be appropriate. If the period of time is known then this can be stated in a `Retry-After` header. The search engines are likely to hold on to the resource for as along as possible. But a "few weeks" might be too long?

If the *original* page is not available for a lengthy period of time then the search engines will likely drop the page from the SERPs regardless of status code.

Comment: Why not use 307? This one is really Temporary Redirect as opposed to 503 Server Error.

Comment: Returning a 503 is a misdirection, as this code should be for genuine problems with the server. Based on the first half of your answer, I think maybe I'll stick with returning a 404. It's the truth after all! Thanks for your response.

Comment: @tonydoe I don't think any 3xx redirection is really appropriate. The page has been _removed_ and there is no equivalent page to redirect to. Yes, a 503 may not be appropriate in this situation. However, a 503 doesn't necessarily indicate a lasting "error" state - it is a [recognised method of indicating "planned maintenance" / "temporary downtime"](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html) in order to minimise the effect on rankings.

Comment: A custom 404 is probably the best bet (for users as well). It is usually preferable for users to see a custom 404 with explanation and appropriate links, rather than be auto-redirected to the home page without explanation.

Comment: @w3dk what I mean is just that the questioner noted that users will be actually redirected to the homepage and this redirection would be active for a few weeks. It only seems logical to use Temporary Redirect code for bots.

Comment: Google considers redirecting just for bots to be cloaking.  It is against the Google Webmaster Guidelines.

Comment: @Kieran Google will not going to remove your 404 page in just few months like 1 or 2, it really takes to long time to gone, since they have already cache version of that page to show user. Some important pages take years to gone. 404 means Google did not found that page, and will come back again after some time. I still see 1 year old 404 in my search console, look's like Google still waiting for it, in hope of that URL will live again soon.